# Unable to send E-mails using Swift Mailer

Tags: html-email, swiftmailer, php

```
$transport = Swift_SmtpTransport::newInstance('smtp.gmail.com', 465, "ssl")

->setUsername('username')
->setPassword('password');

$username = $_SESSION['username'];  
$from = $_POST['from'];
$to =  $_POST['to'];
$subject = $_POST['subject'];
$body = $_POST['message'];

$message = Swift_Message::newInstance($subject)

->setFrom(array($from => $username))
->setTo(array($to))
->setBody($body);

$mailer = Swift_Mailer::newInstance($transport);
$result = $mailer->send($message);
```

Error returned on web browser:

Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Swift_TransportException' with message 'Connection could not be established with host smtp.gmail.com [Unable to find the socket transport "ssl" - did you forget to enable it when you configured PHP? #157919304]' in C:\Program Files\xampp\htdocs\healthcare system\swift\lib\classes\Swift\Transport\StreamBuffer.php:259 Stack trace: #0 C:\Program Files\xampp\htdocs\healthcare system\swift\lib\classes\Swift\Transport\StreamBuffer.php(64): Swift_Transport_StreamBuffer->_establishSocketConnection() #1 C:\Program Files\xampp\htdocs\healthcare system\swift\lib\classes\Swift\Transport\AbstractSmtpTransport.php(115): Swift_Transport_StreamBuffer->initialize(Array) #2 C:\Program Files\xampp\htdocs\healthcare system\swift\lib\classes\Swift\Mailer.php(80): Swift_Transport_AbstractSmtpTransport->start() #3 C:\Program Files\xampp\htdocs\healthcare system\mail_process.php(32): Swift_Mailer->send(Object(Swift_Message)) #4 {main} thrown in C:\Program Files\xampp\htdocs\healthcare system\swift\lib\classes\Swift\Transport\StreamBuffer.php on line 259

Comment: Pls help.... I've been trying so many methods to send Mails by PHP but all has been failing me... This function is crucial for my Final Year Project to run well..... Help is needed! Thank you all  in advance....

Comment: This error showed up after doing the syntax corrections given by MIss Poo. This is also the traditional error that I have been getting when I tried to send even test emails via Swift Mailer. Back to ground zero. What has to be configured in PHP? or is it a Swift Mailer config error.... Pls Help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace the below code:

```
$message = Swift_Message::newInstance('$subject')

->setFrom(array('$from' => '$username'))
->setTo(array('$to'))
->setBody('$body');
```

With

```
$message = Swift_Message::newInstance($subject)

->setFrom(array($from => $username))
->setTo(array($to))
->setBody($body);
```

As here you are using the single quotation mark that is the problem in your code.

Answer (score 0):

replace this

->setUsername('username')

->setPassword('password');

with

$transport->setUsername('username');   /* note: user name is your gmail username(eg
                                       asaa@gmail.com) */

$transport->setPassword('password');   /*password is your gmail password*/